# How do I make this to where I can call it through a DLL?

Tags: c#, class, twitter, methods

I'm creating a Class library where I can import the DLL in later projects and just call the below to send a DirectMessage to Twitter user. It works if I include the code directly in the Form1 class but I dont want that I want to be able to do something like in VB:

```
Dim dm as New SendDM
dm.SendDirectMessage(user, message)
```

and it go. Any ideas? Im not that familiar with C# so should I make it public? Put it in it's own class file like SendDM.cs or what?

```
        private void SendDM(string user, string message)
    {
        if (message.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your tweet must be at least 1 character long!");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // URL-encode the tweet...
            string tweet = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message);

            // And send it off...
            string xml = _oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(
                oAuthTwitter.Method.POST,
                 "http://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages/new.xml",
                "?user=" + user + "&text=" + message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while posting your tweet:\n\n" + ex.Message);
            return;
        }

       message = String.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Create a "Class Library" project. Insert your code and compile it.

Comment: Dont forget to make your method and your class Public.

Comment: And i would prefer to make that Method Static !

Answer (score 1):

from a class library you should not use `MessageBoxe` to notify exceptions or validate input parameters, just throw the exception from the catch instead of return and throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if input parameter doesn't validate.

Said this, you should have a public class `SendDM` and inside it a public method `SendDirectMessage` if you wish to use your VB code shown above to send the message.

Also, you do not need to reset message to `String.Empty` at the end of the `SendDirectMessage` method.